# Upgrading from WSS 3.0 to Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, wss-3.0, migration

I have got sharepoint 2010 installed but I can't see any of the documents / calenders, when I run the upgrade it references a site that is claims doesn't exist.

I ran the following in PS: `stsadm -o enumallwebs -databasename PEMSharePointDBForWebVSrv4183`

and got the following results.

```
<Databases>
  <Database SiteCount="2" Name="PEMSharePointDBForWebVSrv4183" DataSource="ED-WSS\SharePoint">
<Site Id="204d9d26-8afe-4acf-9834-70be3c4b8ca8" OwnerLogin="SSP\adminuser" InSiteMap="True">
  <Webs Count="1">
    <Web Id="8b5fa698-13fd-4666-a3d3-1e506695da97" Url="/" LanguageId="1033" TemplateName="STS#0" TemplateId="1" />
  </Webs>
</Site>The site with the id 16ffd98e-8b72-4dfd-ad51-8a933624f56c could not be found.
```

now all the documents in the database appear to reference the site that it is not happy with.

is there a way to create it, or have I missed some really simple step somewhere.

thanks in advance